# insert newline character into string in php as a delimiter

Tags: php, html, newline, concatenation

I have a form on the front end with two text areas separated by a hidden input, like so:

```
<textarea name="top">
blah 
blah 
</textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="foo" value="some string" />
<textarea name="bottom"> 
blah 
blah 
</textarea>
```

When I get this form on the serverside, I want to concat a newline character before and after the hidden input to like so:

```
$text = $_Post['top'] . "\n" . $_Post['foo'] . "\n" . $_Post['bottom'];
```

for the purpose of using that newline char as a delimiter for explode later in my program like so:

```
$arrayOfTextSplitByNewlines = explode("\n", $text);
```

My issue is that the newlines I add to the string aren't being recognized by explode as newline chars, rather they're being treated as string literals.  i've tried single quotes, double quotes, escaping the newline, etc. but for some reason, they're just strings.  Any insight as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why not using a different delimiter? Something like ||

Comment: What if the textareas contain newlines?

Comment: can't you simply use a comma ?

Comment: The code you've written should work, the newlines should be recognized. Are you sure you're not using single quotes? `\n` is only translated to newline in double quotes.

Comment: But why are you doing it this way in the first place? Why not just make an array `$text = array($_POST['top'], $_POST['foo'], $_POST['bottom']);`

Comment: there are several reasons why i don't want to use a different delimiter...lots of other dependencies in the code that i don't want to change if possible. Besides, there is no reason why this shouldn't work so if you're able to answer the question, please do.

Comment: @Barmar - I'm certain i'm not using single quotes...i actually tried both (though i know single quotes should not be translated into a newline char).  the reason I'm concating the string in the first place is the function i'm passing it to, which is being called many other places in the code base, expects a string not an array.  This is a corner case where i'm having to build the string from 3 separate variables.  the rest just have one string.  I'd rather not refactor for a corner case

Comment: Can you post `var_dump($text)` and `var_dump($arrayOfTextSplitByNewlines)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

implode!  Thank you @barmar for giving me the idea to send it as an array.  I don't want to do that for the reasons mentioned above BUT I was able to build an array from the strings:

```
$textArray = array($_POST['top'], $_POST['foo'], $_POST['bottom']);
```

then implode it with the newline char as the delimiter.

```
$text = implode("\n", $textArray);
```

everything else worked as hoped in the other places throughout the code.  Not sure why it wasn't working before without implode so if you've got any insights, i'm all ears.  Thanks again @barmar